# Why does `<MovingItem/>` disappear when I use this.state.reachedBottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

https://codepen.io/blenderous/pen/ZEOMjww?editors=1010

I would like to add a class called "move" to `<MovingItem/>` when the page hits the bottom. For this, I use

```
this.setState({'reachedBottom': true})
```

Then I use *this.state.reachedBottom* in the *getClassName* function.

But `<MovingItem/>` disappears when I run the code.

Comment: can you share more code for better understanding?

Comment: I have shared the entire code in the codepen https://codepen.io/blenderous/pen/ZEOMjww?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the initial state. Add this to your component:

```
state = {
    reachedBottom: false
}
```

Reason for having an initial state in your case:

```
getClassName() {
    if (this.state.reachedBottom) {
      return "move";
    }
  }
```

In the above function since the state is initially undefined, `this.state.reachedBottom` throws an error as the key `reachedBottom` doesn't exist yet.